# ThreeJS Fog or Shaders or Lighting

Tags: three.js

I've been looking on this website https://www.igoodi.eu/mission and trying to experiment on how they do that blue/teal blurry fog thing at the top left and also at the bottom. I'm new to ThreeJS and just know the basics.

I am experimenting the fog and lighting to implement that specific section of that website but no luck. I hope someone can help me pinpoint on the things that I should know on how to implement that one.

[Screenshot pointing sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrQzk.png)

Comment: You might want to include a screenshot.. I couldn't tell which effect you were talking about and theres a lot going on in that site.

Comment: Hi @manthrax, I updated the description above and added the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the teal tinted "vignette" you're after, you could do that with a single plane facing the camera with a transparent texture assigned to it.. then you can put whatever tint you want in your texture.

But there are basically infinite ways to achieve that effect.. If I had to guess, based on the site and the other stuff they are doing, I think it's a post processing effect done via the THREE.EffectsComposer.